# Amazon SP-API Update Inventory Stock

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api

i'm trying to update stocks of my inventory Amazon Catalog using SP-API.
This is my code:

```
  private static IRestRequest CreateRequestFeedDocument()
   {
      IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("feeds/2020-09-04/documents", Method.POST);

      AmazonInventory obj = new AmazonInventory();
      obj.SKU = "GD4297-44";
      obj.Available = "true";
      obj.Quantity = "20";
      string xml = string.Empty;

      using (var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
      {
         var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
         serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, obj);
         xml = stringwriter.ToString();
      }

      restRequest.AddParameter("contentType", xml, ParameterType.RequestBody);
      restRequest.AddQueryParameter("MarketplaceIds", "APJ6JRA9NG5V4,A1PA6795UKMFR9,A13V1IB3VIYZZH,A1805IZSGTT6HS,A1F83G8C2ARO7P,A1RKKUPIHCS9HS,A2NODRKZP88ZB9");


      AssumeRoleResponse assumeRoleResponse = null;

      Task.Run(async () =>
      {
         assumeRoleResponse = await GetAssumeRoleTokenDetail();
      }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

      // LWA credentials for app in amazon seller central
      var clientId = AmazonCredentials.Default.ClientId;
      var clientSecret = AmazonCredentials.Default.ClientSecret;
      // generate refresh token with 'Authorize' action for app in amazon seller central
      var refreshToken = AmazonCredentials.Default.RefreshToken;

      var lwaAuthCreds = new LWAAuthorizationCredentials
      {
         ClientId = clientId,
         ClientSecret = clientSecret,
         RefreshToken = refreshToken,
         Endpoint = new Uri("https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token")
      };

      restRequest = new LWAAuthorizationSigner(lwaAuthCreds).Sign(restRequest);

      var awsAuthCreds = new AWSAuthenticationCredentials
      {
         AccessKeyId = assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
         SecretKey = assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
         Region = AmazonCredentials.Default.Region
      };

      restRequest.AddHeader("x-amz-security-token", assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.SessionToken);

      restRequest = new AWSSigV4Signer(awsAuthCreds)
         .Sign(restRequest, restClient.BaseUrl.Host);

      return restRequest;
   }

restClient = new RestClient(live_url_base);
      IRestRequest restRequest = CreateRequestFeedDocument();
      var response = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

I get the following error

```
{
  "errors": [
   { 
      "code": "InvalidInput",
      "message": "Invalid Input",
      "details": ""
    }
   ]
}
```

On the web I found this solution

adding this line:

```
      restRequest.AddJsonBody(new { contentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8" });
```

I don't get Invalid inout error but I'm getting

```
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Where I'm wrong?

Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw5JC.png

Answer (score 1):

This is a new Announcement from Amazon.

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/use-case-guides/feeds-api-use-case-guide/feeds-api-use-case-guide_2021-06-30.md#step-3-upload-the-feed-data

works perfectly!

https://github.com/clousale/amazon-sp-api-php/issues/61#issuecomment-825542099

Comment: The second link is now dead.